# Howto construct MigrateSQLMap in a composite key scenario

Tags: drupal-7, migrate

How can we instantiate a MigrateSQLMap in case if a table had composite primary key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MigrateSQLMap takes an array, you can set multiple fields in the source definition:

```
// The source ID here is the one retrieved from each data item in the XML file, and
// used to identify specific items
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
  array(
    'vendor_code' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 250,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'client_code' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 250,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
  ),
  MigrateDestinationEntityAPI::getKeySchema('vendor')
);
```

In the code above, *vendor_code* and *client_code* are the components of the composite key.